# Recursive SQL joins

Tags: sql, join, powerpivot

I have a table and want to recursively join this table with itself to get a hierarchy. So This is how the table looks:

```
IDParent | IDChild | Level | Value
----------------------------------
1      |      2     |   0  |  500
2      |      3     |   1  |  700
3      |      4     |   2  |  900
...           ...       ...
```

And this is how it should look like:

```
IDLvl0 | IDLvl1 | ValueLvl1 | IDLevel2 | ValueLvl2 ...
------------------------------------------------------
1      |    2   |    500    |     3    |    700 ...
```

The preferred result table should be used with PowerPivot, so if you know a simple solution to get the result table with mdx or PowerPivot it would also help me a lot :)

Thank you

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> **Simple solution:**

the `Hierarchy` table `INNER JOIN` itself with the `ON T1.IDChild = T2.IDParent` clause.
use as many `INNER JOIN Hierarchy T2 ON T1.IDChild = T2.IDParent` clauses as you need for getting more hierarchy levels.

```
CREATE TABLE Hierarchy (IDParent int, IDChild  int, Level int, Value int);
INSERT Hierarchy VALUES (1,2,0,500),(2,3,1,700),(3,4,2,900);

SELECT T1.IDChild, T1.IDParent, T2.IDChild, T2.IDParent, T3.IDChild, T3.IDParent
FROM Hierarchy T1 
        INNER JOIN Hierarchy T2 ON T1.IDChild = T2.IDParent
        INNER JOIN Hierarchy T3 ON T2.IDChild = T3.IDParent
```

[image: SELF INNER JOIN Result]

> **CTE (Common Table Expression) solution:**
>   **Anchor section** will get the root of the tree and **Recursive member definition** will get all other records.

```
WITH CTE (IDParent, IDChild, [Level], Value, LVL)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT IDParent, IDChild, [Level], Value, 0 as LVL 
    FROM Hierarchy AS h
    WHERE h.IDParent = 1
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition : will help us calculate true on-the-fly recursive hierarchy levels 
    SELECT h.IDParent, h.IDChild, h.[Level], h.Value, LVL + 1
    FROM Hierarchy AS h
    INNER JOIN CTE
        ON h.IDParent = CTE.IDChild
    where (h.IDChild <> 1)
)
select * from CTE
```

[image: Recursive CTE Result]

Comment: Yes the simple solution is how it should look like. But is there a solution to do this automatically ? so when you have e.g. 30 levels it's much work to write this much the join clauses